# Increment input field value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I want every time when user enter number ,print the new one + old one in console

here is html script

```
 <input type="number"value=""/>
 <button>click</button>
```

my jquery code

```
$("button").click(function (){
    var x = $("input").val();
    x+=x;
    console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What do you call old value? What do you call new value?

Comment: you can combine jquery `focusin` (https://api.jquery.com/focusin/) to save the value and `focusout` (https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) to sum the new and old values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize the value outside somewhere to keep its state.

html

```
<input type="number" id="inp" value=""/>
<button>click</button>
```

js

```
var x = 0;

$("button").click(function (){
    var y = parseInt($("#inp").val());
    x+=y;
    console.log(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help to you. refer the working demo.

```js
var thevalue = 0;
$("#click").click(function(){
  
  $("#display").text("The Value is :");
   var theinput_value = parseInt($("#num").val());
   thevalue += theinput_value;
  
  $("#display").append(thevalue);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter the nubmer : <input type="number" id="num"><button id="click">Click on me !</button>

<br>
<p id="display">The Value is :</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure x is a global variable so you can save it's value and used each time the click handler is triggered.

I added input casting to avoid string concatenation when using the [addition assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment).

```
var x = 0;     
$("button").click(function (){
     // Get the input
      var current_input = parseInt($("input").val());
     // If input is not a number set it to 0
      if (isNaN(current_input)) current_input = 0;
     // Add the input to x
      x+=current_input;
     // Display it
      console.log(x);
});
```